# merge many txt file contents and skip first line in batch command file

Tags: text, batch-file, merge, batch-processing, skip

I want to create a Batch command file to merge text file with extension ".mf"
However, each file contains date in the first line, which I donot want in the final output file, Please advice how do I get rid of the date line from each file while mergingin into one big txt file.

I have used the following command for merging the txt files for a batch file.

```
copy *.mf big.one
ren big.one filename.mf
```

Example:

```
2013218;
a
b
c
d
```

-

```
2013218;
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

The output must be like below:

```
2013218;
a
b
c
d
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

The sorting does not matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@echo off
del big.one 2> NUL
for %%f in (*.mf) do (
   if not exist big.one (
      copy "%%f" big.one
   ) else (
      for /F  "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
         echo %%a>> big.one
      )
   )
)
set /P fileDate=< big.one
ren big.one filename_%fileDate:~0,-1%.mf
```

This solution does not preserve empty lines from second file on; this may be fixed, if needed.

Comment: Thankx Aacini,

It worked perfectly fine. I can now save the manual work I do everyday.

just a another small query regarding the file created above. I want the file to be saved as <filename>__<YYYYMMDD>.mf Where the date & format is same as in the first line of the file.

Comment: I have a similar process, where I have to merge many files in .txt extension. But this command does not work well. The file is created correctly, but the output file does not have extension ".txt"